# How to manage screen for Storm device

Tags: java, blackberry, mobile-application

I am working for Blackberry application. In which i need to develop application for 4 kinds of resolution as mentioned below:-

640X480
480X360
320X480
& 
360X480

I've developed application for 640X480 very first successfully. 
Then for managing UI for other resolution i created two methods for setting Padding as UI concern. Please have a look over these methods:-

```
 public int scalePX(double i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    double ratio = i/640;
    i = Display.getWidth() * ratio;
    return (int)i;

}

public int scalePY(double i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    double ratio = i/480;
    i = Display.getHeight() * ratio;
    return (int)i;


}
```

As expected it's working perfectly for two other resolution that are Horizontal devices (480X360, 320X480).

But this is not working for [360X480 (Vertical Device)] while it should be. Can anybody explain me why this is not managing this particular device's resolution and what can i do the best now because i wouldn't prefer to code for this resolution separately.

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use an if else condition na ?. if(320x480) then set your values say i=10 , else if(360x480) then set i=20, amd so on.

Comment: I don't understand your idea. FYI, it is provided padding value this is not fixed by me. I need an idea to make it compatible for 360X480 in the same way its working for others. can you explain why this method is not working for 360X480 particularly.

Comment: put an if condition- ie if (360-480)then set padding to a fixed value(corresponding to that screen.) else if(320-480)then set another fixed value and so on.